# Any professional software to help me burn my AVI movie to DVD?

Tags: dvd, avi, dvd-burning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best free AVI to DVD converter](https://superuser.com/questions/56855/best-free-avi-to-dvd-converter)

I want to burn a movie to a dvd but the problem is that this movie is in the .avi format. Is it possible to burn a .avi file to a dvd. Also tell me how to get this to work. are you familiar with any program which will help me in this matter. Please suggest a suitable burner application. 
Appreciate your early reply so much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

I use [DeVeDe](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html) myself.